# rkhunter checking for hidden ports skipped

Tags: 14.10, rkhunter

I have got `rkhunter` version `1.4.2` installed on my Ubuntu 14.10 machine, and every time that I run the command:

```
sudo rkhunter --checkall
```

I get this output about half way through:

```
  Performing checks on the network ports
    Checking for backdoor ports                              [ None found ]
    Checking for hidden ports                                [ Skipped ]
```

Why does it say that it `Skipped` checking for hidden ports? Is this something which is good for it to do (to check for hidden ports)? And if it would be good for it to check for hidden ports, then how do I get it to? Do I need to enable something in the config file? Or install some other software or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is disabled by default because it depend on `unhide-tcp` and this is generally not installed (it is listed when installing rkhunter as optioinal).

```
sudo rkhunter --enable hidden_ports
```

will have it scan for hidden ports. It will error out if `unhide-tcp` is not installed. `unhide` is in the software center so ...

```
sudo apt-get install unhide
```

will install it or see Software Center:

[image]